# Wordpress модификация главного запроса

Tags: wordpress, wp-query

в вордпрессе, например в архивах, есть вывод вида:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php the_post(); ?>
/*что-то выводим*/
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

скажите, можно ли (если можно, то как) модифицировать запрос, чтобы добавить в вывод фильтр по мета-полям?

я попробовал такой код, нашел в документации:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_modify_query_filter' );
function foo_modify_query_filter( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['wc_query'] == "product_query"){
            $query->set( 'cat', 1);
        }
}
```

он вроде как фильтрует, а как сделать фильтр по мета-полям - не пойму. пробую так:

```
            $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
                                'meta_key'     => 'price',
                                'meta_value'     => '890',
                            ) );
```

не срабатывает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Вы правильно модифицируете запрос через хук pre_get_posts(), но у вас не правильная вложенность данных 'meta_query'. Попробуйте обернуть в еще один массив. Пример ниже:

```php
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
       array(
          'meta_key'   => 'price',
          'meta_value' => '890',
    ) ) );
```